# snmptrap SNMPv3 with selected client ip address

Tags: shell, snmp, snmp-trap

I would like to send trap and specify clientaddress

As I search there is two ways:

1. edit /etc/snmp/snmp.conf and set: clientaddr [IP_OF_DEVICE]
2. specify IP as parameter: --clientAddr="[IP_OF_DEVICE]"

When i try to issue command:

```
snmptrap -v 3 -l noAuthNoPriv -u SomeUser -n "" AGENT_IP .1.3.6.1.4.1.161.5.2 .1.3.6.1.4.1.161.1.2.3.4 5
```

It gives an error

```
getaddrinfo(AGENT_IP, NULL, ...): Address family for hostname not supported
```

When I not specify clientadress it works as expected but it use IP of the machine where I issed a command as a client IP

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of this I have to:

- Define virtual interface for ip of device which you want to simulate
- Specify protocol of agent ( by default when I set clientaddr in /etc/snmp/snmp.conf it looks like it tried to use IPv6 for agent )

  snmptrap -v 3 -l noAuthNoPriv -u SomeUser -n "" udp:AGENT_IP ...